# SpringBoot parallel SELECTs on view slow down PostgreSQL query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I don't know if this is a problem with my SpringBoot application or a problem with my PostgreSQL DB.

Do you have any idea where the bottleneck might be? Postgres or maybe SpringBoot configuration?

I use **Postgres via docker with version 15.2** (which is the latest) - I may have to make some adjustments here?

I am running 30 parallel SELECT queries (using JPA) on my PostgreSQL DB on a view through my application. The speed of each query decreases a lot due to this parallelization.

If I run **only one thread**, so the queries run sequentially, it takes between **60 and 100ms / per query**.

If I work **with 10 threads**, then each individual query requires between **140 - 500ms**.

If I work **with 30 threads**, then each individual query takes **between 500 - 900ms**.

My idea was actually that if all the queries run in parallel, they only need 100 - 200ms.

My connection pool is already set to 50.
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=40
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=50

This is how I measure the times:

```
log.debug("Searching for customer by id " + id);
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Customer> customerList = this.customerRepository.findById(id);
log.debug("Finished " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms for customer by id " + id);
```

I am working with a JpaRepository:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, String>.
```

Do I need to configure my postgreSQL DB differently?
Is there a bottleneck somewhere in my application? I already measure the times directly before starting the query and after it has been completed.

- Host computer has 8 CPUs
- Postgres Docker Container runs without CPU or RAM limitation
- Application runs on the host computer too

Comment: How many cores is the docker container allowed to use? How many cores does the docker *host* have? Unless you have 30 cores and a really good I/O system, then obviously running more processes than the server has cores will make things slower. Many docker images also use Linux distributions that aren't known for their high-performance as well (e.g. Alpine Linux).

Comment: The postgres container runs without restriction on RAM and CPU

Comment: So how many cores does the _host_ computer have? And is the container running on the same computer where your application is running?

Comment: Host computer has 8 CPUs and the application is running on the host computer

Comment: Why is this surprising?  You can't summon infinite CPUs from the void.  Your db can only use the resources it has.  Maybe there is a reason to think it should do better, but you need to explain that reason.

Comment: The reason I think it should work better is that In my opinion Postgres should work with parallel threads to meet my needs. If I make a request with 30 threads, Postgres only uses a small percentage of the resources it could use. About 30% of the CPU and 500MB of RAM.

I think there might be a way to reconfigure Postgres to use more resources and/or more threads. Maybe there is a lack of threads in Postgres due to a misconfiguration.